# How do I display list of items (key value pairs) in React (JSX)?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I need to display my Projects list on each tab (technology) of my react page. There will be multiple projects on each tab.

Projects.js

```
    returnCard = (objJSON) => {

    const projects = Object.values(objJSON);
    var projectList = projects.map(
        (project, index) => {
            console.log('index = ', index, 'Project Name = ', project.projectName) 
// this gives me the right values, yet nothing is rendered if I remove the "async await from toggleCategories()"

            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>QWERTY</h1>
                    <Project key={index} projectName={project.projectName} projectDescription={project.projectDescription} />

                </div>
            )
        })

}

toggleCategories = async() => {
    const arrReact = [
        {
            projectName: 'todo-app',
            projectDescription: " Sample Description "
        },
        {
            projectName: 'react-project-2',
            projectDescription: " Sample Description "
        },
        {
            projectName: 'react-project-3',
            projectDescription: " Sample Description "
        },
    ];


    const arrNode = [
        {
            projectName: 'node-project-1',
            projectDescription: " Sample Description "
        },
        {
            projectName: 'node-project-2',
            projectDescription: " Sample Description "
        },
        {
            projectName: 'node-project-3',
            projectDescription: " Sample Description "
        },
    ];
```

calling the returnCard() function here

```
    if (this.state.activeTab === 0) {
        return (await this.returnCard(arrReact));
    }
    else if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
        return (await this.returnCard(arrNode));
    }

}
```

Rendering with the toggleCategories functions

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="category-tabs">
            <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab} onChange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })} ripple>
                <Tab>React-Redux</Tab>
                <Tab>Node.js</Tab>
            </Tabs>
            <Grid className="projects-grid">
                <Cell col={12}>
                    <div>{this.toggleCategories()}</div> // this line throws the error
                </Cell>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

This is the Error I am getting:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Why do you await the `returnCard`? Other than that, the `returnCard` doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: As Caramiriel said, you should be returning "projectsList" which is the return of your array.map. That is what contains all the elements.

Comment: How do I return projectsList? @Caramiriel It does have a return statement.

Comment: According to the code above it does not. Refer to my answer below...

Comment: Well now it says "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." I have already added key ={index} to the project element, why doesn't that work?

Comment: I updated my answer for your key fix. The key needs to be on the parent element. Is there a reason my answer is marked as unuseful?

Comment: I did not mark it unuseful :). I was in fact wondering why you deleted it. Thanks, it helped.

Comment: Alright, I may have upset someone... @Caramiriel? Glad I could help.

Comment: @JavanPoirier not at all, didn't visit SO for a bit. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const returnCard = (objJSON) => {
const projects = Object.values(objJSON);
var projectList = projects.map(
    (project, index) => {
        console.log('index = ', index, 'Project Name = ', project.projectName)
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <h1>QWERTY</h1>
                <Project projectName={project.projectName} projectDescription={project.projectDescription} />

            </div>
        )
    })

return projectList;
}
```